# cannot be cast to hibernate.HibernateSession while run jsp

Tags: java, hibernate

I was trying to write my first Hibernate project. But I got an exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction cannot be cast to hibernate.HibernateSession

This is how I code session methods.

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class HibernateSession {

    static Connection.NewHibernateUtil hibernateutil;
    static SessionFactory sessionfactory;
    static Session session;
    static Transaction transaction;

    private HibernateSession() {
    }

    public static HibernateSession getHSConnection() {
        if (transaction == null) {
            session = Connection.NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        }
        return (HibernateSession) transaction;
    }

    public static void closeHSConnection() {
        if (transaction != null) {
            session.flush();
            transaction.commit();
        }
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Are there any errors in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast an object to your class when it is an instance of a completely different class (JDBCTransaction)

```
  return (HibernateSession) transaction; // this is the error
```

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359760/2408342) Joakim's explanation is perfect.

You have a couple of options depending on what you really want.

- If you need `HibernateSession` object (an object from the class which you have written), change the return statement of `getHSConnection()` to,

  ```
  return new HibernateSession();
  ```
- Or if you need the newly created `org.hibernate.Transaction` then change your method

  ```
  public static Transaction getHSConnection() {
      ...
      return transaction;
  }
  ```

---

But I suggest that you should return neither of those. Return the `org.hibernate.Session`. Because,

1. I don't see any instance variables in your class `HibernateSession` so there's no point of returning an object of a class with static variables and methods, in fact that should be the reason why your have a `private` constructor for that class.
2. You can always get the current transaction using the method `beginTransaction()`. the javadoc says,

   > *...If a new underlying transaction is required, begin the transaction. Otherwise continue the new work in the context of the existing underlying transaction...*

So I suggest you change your method like this,

```
public static Session getHSConnection() {
    ...
    return session;
}
```

and when you need to commit the transaction,

```
Session s = HibernateSession.getHSConnection();
s.beginTransaction().commit();
```

Remember it all depends on your requirement.